# how to access current queue size in NS2

Tags: tcl, ns2

i have simulated a 2 node tcp based communication with duplex link and queue in NS2 using TCL script. And i want to access the current queue size during communication of the nodes.
      so how can i access the current queue size and assign it into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use this codeto get cwnd size on terminal.

```
proc plotWindow {tcpSource outfile} {
global ns
set now [$ns now]
set cwnd [$tcpSource set cwnd_]
puts  $outfile  "$now $cwnd"
$ns at [expr $now+0.1] "plotWindow $tcpSource  $outfile"
}
$ns  at  0.0  "plotWindow $tcp1  stdout"
```